# Solving System of Equations:

Tags: algorithm, function

I have the following problem:

f(x) is defined as f1(x) between 0 and 10, f2(x) between 10 and 20 and 0 otherwise. The integral of f(x) between 0 and 20 needs to be greater than or equal to a value K.

g(x) is defined as g1(x) between 0 and 5, g2(x) between 5 and 20 and 0 otherwise. The integral of g(x) between 0 and 20 needs to be greater than or equal to a value Q.

For any x, the sum of f(x) and g(x) cannot exceed a value R.

I assume there is quite some elaborate theory behind it, and was wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction to devise an algorithm that can generate f1(x), f2(x), g1(x) and g2(x)?

EDIT: I would like to add that for a given K and Q the interest is to keep R as low as possible.

Thanks :)

Comment: This question looks like it would fit better on [cs.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way the question is stated I assume that f1(x), f2(x), g1(x) and g2(x) are (non-negative) constant functions. Then this is a [linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) (LP) problem, which can be solved for example using the [simplex algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm).

The problem, expressed as LP problem, would be:

```
10*x1 + 10*x2 >= K
5*x3 + 15*x4 >= Q
x1 + x3 <= R
x1 + x4 <= R
x2 + x4 <= R

Variables: x1, x2, x3, x4, R
Minimize R
```

You can implement the LP solver your own or use an existing library or tool. For example to solve the problem for K=23 and Q=42 using the GNU Linear Programming Kit (GLPK):

```
var x1;
var x2;
var x3;
var x4;
var R;

s.t. rel1: 10*x1 + 10*x2 >= 23;
s.t. rel2: 5*x3 + 15*x4 >= 42;
s.t. rel3: x1 + x3 <= R;
s.t. rel4: x1 + x4 <= R;
s.t. rel5: x2 + x4 <= R;

minimize obj: R;

solve;

printf "Result: %f %f %f %f %f\n", x1, x2, x3, x4, R;

end;
```

Execute with `glpsol --math q22883102.mod`:

```
...
Result: 1.150000 1.150000 2.100000 2.100000 3.250000
```

PS: This particular problem always yields `x1 = x2 = K / 20` and `x3 = x4 = Q / 20` and thus seems a little lightweight for LP. But I guess the question was more about this class of problems than this particular problem.

Comment: It seems OP doesn't specify that f1(x), f2(x), g1(x), and g2(x) are constant non-negative or even linear?  Maybe OP can clarify.

Comment: @cklin: If f1(x), etc. are not constant, then why bother to specify that "f(x) is defined as f1(x) between 0 and 10, f2(x) between 10 and 20 and 0 otherwise.". If f1(x) can be any function and f2(x) can be any function then the definition is equivalent to "supp(f) in [0; 20]" and there is nothing special about x=10. However: In this example `f(x) = K / 20` and `g(x) = Q / 20` would still be a optimal solution if f(x) and g(x) could be any function.

Answer (score 1):

Solving systems of equations is different than a lot of programming tasks.  When you're solving equations, you need a way to treat variables **symbolically** instead of just as **values**.  So you need a way to represent a mathematical *symbol* rather than just a value.  So I think that's where you have to start, if you want to implement your own.

If you don't want to implement your own, [Sympy](https://github.com/sympy/) is a Python implementation of symbolic math solvers.  You could browse their source to see how they handle solving systems of equations.

Specifically: [solvers.py](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/solvers/solvers.py), around line 341, there is a function called `solve` which solves systems of equations.  You can check out how they solve generic systems of equations that way.

Solving a system of equations **numerically** is a lot easier.  you can just brute force it in that case: you just keep modifying the parameters until you find the values that work.